# How to filter out files with multiple criteria in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Lets say you filter for `cpp` files like so

```
$(wildcard **/*.cpp)
```

But you don't want files that contain the word `foo` and you don't want the file with the exact name `bar.cpp`

How does one use `filter-out` with multiple criteria?

Comment: Wanted to point out that if you think using the `**` construct will cause make's `wildcard` function to search directories recursively like zsh does... it won't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to work. Also recursively.

```
$(filter-out $(wildcard **/bar.cpp) $(wildcard **/*foo*), $(wildcard **/*.cpp))
```

Please also note Etan's simpler suggestion below. Leaving mine only for completeness.

Comment: You don't need to `$(wildcard)` for `bar.cpp` just `%/bar.cpp` will work.

Comment: Even if it's in a subdirectory?

Comment: Yup, even with subdirectories. The `%` matches anything. Try it and see.