# How to use GNU Make filter-out a list of files from a directory?

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I have a list of `cpp` files that I want to exclude from my `Makefile`. I can't apply a wildcard as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36719876/937153); instead, I want to exclude a list of specific file names. How do I do that?

This doesn't seem to work.

```
SRCDIR = ../src

EXCLUDE := file1.cpp,file2.cpp,file3.cpp
SRCS    = $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -name '*.cpp')
SRCS := $(filter-out $(SRCDIR)/$(EXCLUDE) , $(SRCS))
```

Looking at the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html), multiple files can be filtered as:

```
objects=main1.o foo.o main2.o bar.o
mains=main1.o main2.o

$(filter-out $(mains),$(objects))
```

So my question pretty much becomes whether there is a way to exclude `../src/file1.cpp`, `../src/file2.cpp`,  `../src/file3.cpp` by loading value from the variable `SRCDIR`?

Comment: Are you just looking for something like [`$(addprefix $(SRCDIR)/,$(EXCLUDE))`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions)? (Sorry for the rather vague link; you'll have to scroll down a bit.)

Comment: @G.M.Oh yes! That was enough. Thank you. Would you like to add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
SRCS := $(filter-out $(EXCLUDE:%=$(SRCDIR)/%),$(SRCS))
```